# Constrain Eclim to java files

Tags: java, configuration-files, conditionals

I am using eclim and I am loving it! But I had to disable `eclimd-autostart` because it keep trying to fire up eclimd when I pop a `.js` buffer.

```
Autostarting of eclimd is disabled, please start eclimd manually. [2 times]
```

Here its my eclim configuration

```
(use-package eclim
  :ensure t
  :after evil-leader
  :init (custom-set-variables '(eclim-default-workspace "~/workspace/"))
  :if (string-match-p (regexp-quote "cesco") user-login-name)
  :config (progn
        ;; (setq eclimd-autostart t)
        (cond
         ((string-equal system-type "gnu/linux")
          (setq eclim-executable "/opt/eclipse/eclim"))
         ((string-equal system-type "darwin")
          (setq eclim-executable "~/eclipse/Eclipse.app/Contents/Eclipse/eclim")))
        (evil-leader/set-key-for-mode 'java-mode
          "rr" 'eclim-java-find-references
          "rj" 'eclim-java-find-declaration)
        (define-key eclim-mode-map (kbd "C-c C-c") 'eclim-problems-correct)
        (global-eclim-mode)
        ))
```

I also observing a very weird problem when using org-edit-special to edit any language source block. Eclim seems to take the job

```
error in process filter: apply: Not enough arguments for format string
error in process filter: Not enough arguments for format string
eclimd serving at port 9091
```